# xlsxwriter - Creating hyperlink by referencing value from another cell

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write a Python script that creates an excel file using xlsxwriter.

I have a key word in a cell and would like to reference that using the `write_url()` method of xlsxwriter

In cell A1, I have a keyword `demo`.

I am trying to create a hyperlink in cell A2 such that the URL is https://www.website.com/demo

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Hyperlinks')
worksheet.write('A1', 'demo')
worksheet.write_url('A2', 'https://www.website.com/' + A1  , string='Testing')
```

Expected output in cell A2 : `https://www.website.com/demo`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is with an Excel formula:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Hyperlinks')
url_format = workbook.get_default_url_format()

worksheet.write('A1', 'demo')
worksheet.write_formula('A2', '=HYPERLINK("https://www.website.com/" & A1, "Testing")', url_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]